# Cannot loop through different database applying correct formula

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have this python working script:

```py
import pandas as pd

data_path = r'G:\SOCCER\PremierLeague_2021.xlsx'
data = pd.read_excel(data_path)

data['Match_Home'] = data.apply(lambda row: (data['Home'][:row.name] == row['Home']).sum() + (data['Away'][:row.name] == row['Home']).sum(), axis=1)
data['Match_Away'] = data.apply(lambda row: (data['Home'][:row.name] == row['Away']).sum() + (data['Away'][:row.name] == row['Away']).sum(), axis=1)

data['Key'] = data['Home'] + data['Match_Home'].astype(str) + data['Away'] + data['Match_Away'].astype(str)

output_path = r'G:\SOCCER\PremierLeague_2021.xlsx'
data.to_excel(output_path, index=False)
```

It loads a database from an excel file and it calculates for every current match the progressive number of matches played by each team (both home and away). The key is created for further calculations when we need the mean of a certain N previous matches.

Now I would like to use it with a database that contains different Season, so I need to apply this previous script to each season, without using matches from previous one (so every season will restart with 0 value for every team) but if I try to loop through every season and append the database, the first one is correct, then for the next rows I get 38 as value for every Match_Home and Match_Away column! (every season has 20 teams, so a correct season finish with 37 since the first match is zero).

I tried also splitting database and then applying the script but I got the same results, here's the last script I tried:

```py
import pandas as pd

data_path = r'G:\SOCCER\PremierLeague_AllSeasons.xlsx'
data = pd.read_excel(data_path)


databases = {}
for season in data['Season'].unique():
  
  databases[season] = data[data['Season'] == season].copy()

for season, database in databases.items():
    database['Match_Home'] = database.apply(lambda row: (database['Home'][:row.name] == row['Home']).sum() + (database['Away'][:row.name] == row['Home']).sum(), axis=1)
    database['Match_Away'] = database.apply(lambda row: (database['Home'][:row.name] == row['Away']).sum() + (database['Away'][:row.name] == row['Away']).sum(), axis=1)
  

for season, database in databases.items():
  output_path = r'G:\SOCCER\PremierLeague_{}.xlsx'.format(season)
  database.to_excel(output_path, index=False)
```

This is the part of database interested, so very simple:

[image]

Any help appreciated!

This is what expectd (here you se one season but same for others, it must start with 0):

[image]

Comment: Look at the split-apply-combine page in the pandas docs. You don’t need (and shouldn’t use) any of these loops

Comment: Please show what's your exptected result in OP.

Comment: Added a picture of expected db as i said i expect for all the seasons, but got only the first correctly!